Cant connect DriverManager with postgresql inside kotlin android project
I want to connect my android app to postrgresql database on the server, but first i tried to connect to my local postgresql database. I create db 'mydb',  create user 'myuser'. Inside mainActivity.kt i tried to connect to db with DriverManager, but i get an error. I start my app and when app download on virtual phone it stops work and closes.
My MainActivity.kt:
package com.example.testingbd

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.util.Properties

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
    }


    val url: String = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb"
    val props = Properties().apply {
        setProperty("user", "myuser")
        setProperty("password", "Forsash9")
        //setProperty("ssl", "true")
    }
    val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props)


}

My build.gradle:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsKotlinAndroid)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.testingbd"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.testingbd"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

dependencies {
    val version: String = "42.6.0"
    implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql:$version")

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
}

I got this error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.testingbd, PID: 4977
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testingbd/com.example.testingbd.MainActivity}: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3689)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception.
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:320)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190)
    at com.example.testingbd.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:39)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:44)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3676)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1675)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:115)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1106)
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:245)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:241)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:132)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:258)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:263)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:443)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:297)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580) 
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190) 
    at com.example.testingbd.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:39) 
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95) 
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:44) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3676) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3922) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2443) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971) 


Please read: What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?, followed by JDBC vs Web Service for Android and https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/anrs/keep-your-app-responsive
